# Bubble Sorting Explanation

Tags: java

I am writing a bubble code program for my intro to Java class, and it is a very simple assignment. I am just curious as to if my code is correct. The thing is, my code works, but it is different from the normal solution I have seen other people post. I am not sure if I have just done a different sorting method, or if I have just written a different version of bubble sorting.

So below is the code I have written:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class BubbleSort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random ran = new Random();

        int[] list = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            list[i] = ran.nextInt(50);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bubbleSort(list)));
    }

    public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] list)
    {
        int temp;

        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < list.length - 1; j++)
            {
                if(list[j] > list[j + 1])
                {
                    temp = list[j];
                    list[j] = list[j + 1];
                    list[j + 1] = temp;
                }

            }
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

And that works perfectly fine. But I am not sure if it is actually 'bubble sorting'.

Most people have this in their`for loop` when they are writing this same program

`for(int j = 0; j < list.length - 1 - i; i++)`

The question I have is what is the point of doing the `list.length - 1- i` whenever what I have, `list.length - 1` works perfectly fine?

Have I accidentally done a different form of sorting? They both work I am just curious as to why people do `list.length - 1 - i`

Comment: It's a bubble sort.  The `-i` is there to make the inner loop a bit shorter, saving time.  In any bubble sort the largest element is "bubbled" to the end of the array, so you know it's in the right position.  So there's no need to check it over and over each time through the loop.  The number of sorted elements is equal to the number of times the outer loop has run, so the `-i` gets rid of unnecessary tests.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that is the point of bubble sorting. It is supposed to only compare adjacent elements and then do that until the list is sorted. That is the reason for the nested loop. It keeps going until the list is sorted

Comment: You should also start your inner loop at `i` or you are re-checking elements that were already sorted.

Comment: @markspace Ah, now I see. Thank you that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

@markspace gave me the correct answer in the comments so all credit to him.

I will just post this for the sake of proving his answer. I tested my code with 10,000 integers and created a timer to see how long it takes. Whenever I used my code which just had `j < list.length - 1` sorting 10,000 integers took 297 milliseconds on average. Once I changed my for loop to have `j < list.length - 1 - i` it sorted the loop about 35% faster at just 196 milliseconds. As stated by mark, adding the `- i` just prevents the program from re-checking the last elements which are already sorted thus saving time.